# Unresolved identified error in swift do-catch

Tags: jquery, parse-platform, error-handling, swift2

Thanks to the community I solved yesterday issue with error handling while moving to swift 2. These corrections actually created a new error and I don't know how to correct it. Here is the current code which displays some picture posts in a feed:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

ParseHelper.timelineRequestForCurrentUser {
  (result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  self.posts = result as? [Post] ?? []

  for post in self.posts {
    do
    {
      let data = try post.imageFile?.getData()
    }
    catch
    {
      print("Error: \(error)")
      //Handle the error instead of print probably
    }
    post.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)  --> where I get the error message "Use of unresolved identified 'data'"

  }

  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In addition, a new error appears in my ParseHelper file I am referring to in the previous method.

```
static func timelineRequestForCurrentUser(completionBlock: PFArrayResultBlock) {
let followingQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
followingQuery.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)

let postsFromFollowedUsers = Post.query()
postsFromFollowedUsers!.whereKey("user", matchesKey: "toUser", inQuery: followingQuery)

let postsFromThisUser = Post.query()
postsFromThisUser!.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postsFromFollowedUsers!, postsFromThisUser!])
query.includeKey("user")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

// 3
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock) --> I get an error message too here "Cannot convert value of type 'PFArrayResultBlock' to expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultBlock?'"
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Not too experienced with Swift, but the compiler output makes sense.  First, the scope of the `let data` declaration is limited to the `do` block of the do/catch.  In order for the `catch` block to use data, data must be redeclared in the scope surrounding the do/catch...

```
let data : NSData? // assuming type is NSData (my point here is about scope)
do {
    data = try post.imageFile?.getData()
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
    //Handle the error instead of print probably
}
// now data is in scope here...
post.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)
```

The second issue seems to be that the completion block is declared as a function param of type `PFArrayResultBlock` here:

```
static func timelineRequestForCurrentUser(completionBlock: PFArrayResultBlock)
```

...but parse expects a block of type `PFQueryArrayResultBlock` to be passed to `findObjectsInBackground`.  It looks like the difference between those is the expected type of the array element differs slightly (`[PFObject]?` for the query, vs. `[AnyObject]?`).

Comment: Thank you so much. Replacing PFObject has solved the issue for the completionBlock.  

I am still struggling with the post.image. I have tried your solution, but still get the same error: 

Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'Observable<UIImage?>' (aka 'Observable<Optional<UIImage>>'). The code looks like this now:

    let data : NSData?
        do {
          data = try post.imageFile?.getData()
        } catch {
          print("Error: \(error)")
          //Handle the error instead of print probably
        }
        post.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)

Comment: That sounds like a different error than the one expressed in the OP.  It sounds like it's happening on the post.image assignment, and that post.image is not declared exactly as a UIImage.  The code is problematic also because the version of getData() it is using is blocking.  Calling it even once, let alone in a loop will cause the UI to freeze.

Comment: The code ahead defining the post.image, which is when you select an image from your phone is (right above):

  func takePhoto() {
    // instantiate photo taking class, provide callback for when photo is selected
    photoTakingHelper =
      PhotoTakingHelper(viewController: self.tabBarController!) { (image: UIImage?) in
        let post = Post()
        // 1
        post.image.value = image!
        post.uploadPost()
    }
  }

Should I go with a different way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I corrected the issue:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
ParseHelper.timelineRequestForCurrentUser { 
(result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 
self.posts = result as? [Post] ?? [] 
self.tableView.reloadData() } }
```